# Is it possible to integration delphi vcl/Dll with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delphi, dll, vcl

Which mean I want to call function in delphi VCL/ DLL to retrieve information.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the dll is not .Net you will need to use Platform Invoke [DllImport] calls.

Have a look here for windows API examples here [(http://pinvoke.net/)](http://pinvoke.net/) which should help you call your delphi dlls.

Comment: And it also depends on the types you are exporting. Make sure they are not Delphi specific types (no string, no TStringList, etc).

Comment: Instead of PInvoke you could also make a COM/ActiveX library in Delphi which then can be called from C# using interop.

Comment: @Lars This comment is worthy of being an answer

Comment: @David: As fas as I know creating COM/ActiveX libraries requires registration of the library, which may cause additional issues depending on the situation. Sometimes its just easier to access the existing dll driectly without the additional layer.

Comment: @Mark I'm not advocating one over the other. I'm just saying that both are worthy of consideration. The corresponding downside of P/invoke is that it can be quite hard to get right.

Comment: @Mark there is registration free COM since XP. No need to register anything if you don't want to and COM dlls can be deployed privately.

Comment: @Lars: ok, cool, I think I havent looked at Delphi(5) and COM/COM+ since before XP :-)

Comment: Thanks all your information, may I make a conclusion: I can use pinvoke to call functions in delphi(VCL)/DLL, right ?